# How does sammy.js store its routes, are they shared within the same domain and can they be deleted?

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I have an mvc application with 2 sammy applications,
1 for the `'home'` controller and 1 for the `'invoice'` controller.

I've registered a route on the `'home'` and on the `'invoice'` page with the path `"#/about",`
(on both pages an new sammy application is created).
When I navigate to `'/invoice/#about'` somehow the callback on the 'home' page is called.
Off course, the `'#/about'` route should act differently on the `'home'` page then on the `'invoice'` page.

So my question is, how does sammy store its routes and are they shared within the same domain?

Can they be deleted?

If not, do I need to fully destroy my application?

Comment: Please, provide the code that creates Sammy app and configures routes. Also, how do you determine that the wrong callback is called? Am I correct that you have 2 different js files for 2 pages, say, 'home.js' and 'invoice.js'; and when you open '/invoice/#about', the browser hits a breakpoint in the 'home.js' file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [the source code](https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/blob/master/lib/sammy.js), it stores them in a javascript object only:

```
add_route = function(with_verb) {
    var r = {verb: with_verb, path: path, callback: callback, param_names: param_names};
    // add route to routes array
    app.routes[with_verb] = app.routes[with_verb] || [];
    // place routes in order of definition
    app.routes[with_verb].push(r);
};
```

You can also easily check [this tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/WebmailExampleStandalone.html) and see that Sammy doesn't keep anything anywhere: no Web SQL, Local Storage, Cookies, etc. Nothing.

So, the scope of routes configuration is the scope of a Sammy.Application object. Obviously, it cannot exceed the lifetime of a HTML page, i.e. when you navigate browser to another document, the routes are dropped.

Plugins might store routes, although I have no idea what the practical purpose could be.

Comment: Sammy is capable of remembering the last visited hash even after closing the browser. It seems there must be some sort of storage to do this?

Comment: @Thomas Don't know anything about that. Could you provide a link to a live demo? I would suppose such a feature has been implemented in a sample rather than being built into Sammy. It's quite easy to implement, btw. However, I'm only guessing.

Comment: I don't have a live sample at the moment. It is used in John Papa's codecamper single page application, but I don't think the sources are free to download (we've seen it in a Pluralsight course)